# Fancytree does not execute in a Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, fancytree

I am using the fancytree plugin within Bootstrap. It works well on a standard page, however when invoked in a modal, it does nothing.

The function is declared and jQuery().fancytree returns true.

I am unable to also get the debug output, so looks like it is not being invoked at at all

a DIV with id ntree is defined

my HTML in the modal

```
<div id="ntree"><div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Create the tree inside the <div id="tree"> element.
    console.log(jQuery().fancytree);
    if (jQuery().fancytree){
        alert("function exists");
        $("#ntree").fancytree({
            children: [ // Pass an array of nodes.
                {title: "Item 1"},
                {title: "Folder 2", isFolder: true,
                    children: [
                        {title: "Sub-item 2.1"},
                        {title: "Sub-item 2.2"}
                    ]
                },
                {title: "Item 3"}
            ],
            debugLevel: 2
        });
    } else {
        alert("Fancytree is not declared");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I apologise to this forum, for not providing enough information at the initial post. I take this opportunity to provide more information, as well as my findings after more efforts

I am seeking to implement fancytree within a modal dialog in Vtiger CRM. Doubtless, it can be acheived in other ways, as I have done within other UI components of Vtiger, as a Vtiger Widget. The screenshot link below shows the result.

http://screencast.com/t/Wo37GoBMN8R

Comment: Vtiger CRM is a realisation of many open source libraries, principally jQuery and Bootstrap for UI. At the point of the modal invocation, showing on screen, ther are many css annd js which are called prior to the action. 

My challenge is to have it work under a Modal as rendered by Vtiger.

I was able to make a fiddle using the same CSS and js resources as in my Vtiger instance and the fancytree component worked perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/stprasad/fn0udjvo/4/

Comment: I included the CSS and JS for fancy tree in my target enviroment at various load points, including Header.tpl and JSResource.tpl to see if any CSS / JS conflict world resolve.
But nothing seeemed to work.

I suspect that there is a conflict somewhere, because i could confirm the load and existance of the function using if(Jquery.functiontree) which evaluated as true.

More after some efforts

Answer (score 0):

use 'source' property instead of 'children'.

jsfiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/Lu2a67b2/

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Create the tree inside the <div id="tree"> element.
    console.log(jQuery().fancytree);
    if (jQuery().fancytree){
        alert("function exists");
        $("#ntree").fancytree({
            source: [ // Pass an array of nodes.
                {title: "Item 1"},
                {title: "Folder 2", isFolder: true,
                    children: [
                        {title: "Sub-item 2.1"},
                        {title: "Sub-item 2.2"}
                    ]
                },
                {title: "Item 3"}
            ],
            debugLevel: 2
        });
    } else {
        alert("Fancytree is not declared");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. I was using source, but then changed to children after reading another example elsewhere. Perhaps I should have made my point more clear, which I will do so now.

Comment: My environment is within a CRM called Vtiger which uses jQuery, jQuery UI and Bootstrap with plenty of other plugins and addons. I suspect that something loaded, a css or a js along the way is breaking it

I tested on a Tryit with the latest bootstrap and it worked there. I was able to construct the same on http://jsfiddle.net/stprasad/3ksjkL19/ and it worked

I will try and mimic the exact libraries on fiddle and share the results